# NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey did't work when value is NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

dict is NSMutableDictionary; array is NSMutableArray and is NOT nil;

The code:

```
[dict setObject:array forKey:@"key"];
```

There is no error or warning but the dict is null,nothing is set or added.

When I use the code below,it works:

```
[dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:array] forKey:@"Key"];
```

Can anyone tell me why ?

**Update:**
Both `dict` and `array` are local variables and have been initialized.The `dict` is nil.

`NSLog(@"%@", array)` has printed the value of array:

```
({"Title":"firstTitle","Date":"20110101"},{"Title":"secondTitle","Date":"20110102"})
```

---

### UPDATE:

I have made a mistake.The `array` is not null at first,but I emptied it in follow operation.

Thanks for @Bavarious.

Comment: If both `dict` and `array` are not `nil`, then your code is correct. Can you provide more code? How are you testing whether `dict`, `array`, and `[dict objectForKey:@"key"]` are `nil`? Also, is `dict` an instance variable, a property, a local variable?

Comment: How are you creating the array in the first example? Also, what is the exact error you get?

Comment: It is working; it is showing the array. check the following code. NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
 [array addObject:@"Temp"]; 
 NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
 [dic setObject:array forKey:@"array"];
 NSLog(@"%@",dic);

Comment: @Bavarious I have updated the question.@WrightsCS There is no error got.

Comment: If `dict` is nil, then it hasn’t been instantiated and `-objectForKey:` will always return `nil`.

Comment: It’ll be more productive if you provide more code, perhaps the whole method or function where you’re instantiating the dictionary and the array, and adding the array to the dictionary. Otherwise, we can only guess. See http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html

Comment: @Bavarious I checked the code and found that I made a mistake.I have updated the question.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're aware that you're using different capitalizations of "key", right?  `@"Key"` is not the same thing as `@"key"`.

Comment: Is there any difference `@"Key"` or `@"key"` as KEY in `setObject:forKey` ? I just take it for example.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not initialized array in 1st statement. check if its allocated memory or not?

Answer (score -1):

The code seems to be correct. Most probably your `array` is `nil`.
When using `arrayWithArray`, the inserted object will be an array, even if its value itself is set to `nil`.